# JNI Hello World Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This is my first attempt at JNI. My ultimate goal is to get all tasks currently running on a machine, but need to get even a simple example running. I keep getting this error when I try to execute my main program. I have supplied my simple Java main program, the header file generated, and the error.

I do not know what this DLL could be dependent on. It was initially referencing a DLL I tracked down and placed into system32 (msvcr90.dll).

Here is the command I used to compile the C code as well which produced the DLL, OBJ, LIB, EXP and manifest files.

cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\include\win32" -MD -LD HelloWorld.c -FeHelloWorld.dll

```
class HelloWorld {
     private native void print();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HelloWorld().print();
     }
     static {
         System.load("C:\\temp\\HelloWorld.dll");
     }
 }


#include <jni.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "HelloWorld.h"

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return;
 }

/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\temp\HelloWorld.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:7)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: hello try to fallow the step here http://copypastejavacode.blogspot.com/2012/01/basic-java-jni.html it is detailed and i hope you can fallow it.

Comment: What 'unsatisfied link error'? Where is the text of the error? There are at least three different possibilities with three different solutions.

Answer (score 9):

The Unsatisfied Link Error can mean many things went wrong. I would use

```
System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
```

Instead of

```
System.load();
```

As TwentyMiles suggested.

Also, when invoking your program you need to (assuming your DLL is on the same directory as your class files:

java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld

Here's a simple demo I made that calls a Win32 API function (MessageBox)

### Java class

```
class CallApi{
    private native String showMessageBox(String msg);
    private native double getRandomDouble();

    static{
        try{
            System.loadLibrary("CallApi");
            System.out.println("Loaded CallApi");
        }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
            //nothing to do
            System.out.println("Couldn't load CallApi");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        CallApi api = new CallApi();
        double randomNumber = api.getRandomDouble();
        String retval = api.showMessageBox("Hello from Java!\n"+
            "The native random number: "+randomNumber);
            System.out.println("The native string: "+retval);
    }
}
```

### Generated header file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class CallApi */

#ifndef _Included_CallApi
#define _Included_CallApi
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     CallApi
 * Method:    showMessageBox
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_CallApi_showMessageBox
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     CallApi
 * Method:    getRandomDouble
 * Signature: ()D
 */
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_CallApi_getRandomDouble
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

### The C DLL code

```
#include "CallApi.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_CallApi_showMessageBox
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject, jstring js)
{
    //first convert jstring to const char for use in MessageBox
    const jbyte* argvv = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, js, NULL);
    char* argv =(char *) argvv;

    //Call MessageBoxA
    MessageBox(NULL, argv, "Called from Java!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return js;
}

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_CallApi_getRandomDouble
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject)
{
    double num1;
    srand((unsigned)(time(0)));
    num1 = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);

    return num1;
}
```

### Compile instructions

I compile with the Visual C++ express 2008 cl, removing the -ML flag since it causes an exception when the Java code tries to call the native code:

cl /I"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\include" /I"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\include\win32" -LD CallApi.c -FeCallApi.dll

Then, to run the code:

java -Djava.library.path=. CallApi

Comment: I have used `java -classpath . CallApi` instead of `java -Djava.library.path=. CallApi`. Its working only for 1st one and not for what you have gave... Y? Is it so?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not claiming to understand the situation enough to explain it, however some users reported the error when using the "-MD" compiler flag.

For more information see <strike>Java Native Interface (JNI) - Impossible to use VS2005 with Java?</strike> which discusses this problem and offers possible work-arounds and [think techie blog](http://www.think-techie.com/2009/08/java-native-interface-jni.html) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will look into these suggestions as well. I found a working example online I am integrating into my app for my specific needs, but still want to understand the specifics of getting the DLL.

Comment: The link to "Java Native Interface (JNI) - Impossible to use VS2005 with Java?" is broken.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the broken link. Unfortunately, I couldn't update the reference.

Comment: I believe the page originally referenced in the response by Bruno Simões, may be found here: "Thread: Impossible to use VS2005 with Java?" https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1547791 HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should be using

```
System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
```

instead of System.load. LoadLibrary will check your system path (not the Java library path) so make sure that HelloWorld.dll is in a directory where it can found. Also note that it does not require the full path, and you don't need to add the dll extension to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed -MD option and compiled it worked like charm

```
cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\include\win32" -LD HelloWorld.c -FeHelloWorld.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the location (package) of your native function declaration from the java side without updating the h file, and the signature of the method in the c++ side, It won't resolve to the method and will throw unsatisfied..

```
package x;
public class A {
    private native void print();
    ...
}
```

moved to:

```
package x.y;
public class A {
    private native void print();
    ...
}
```

This will require regeneration of the H file (to something like Java_x_y_A_print ).

Note you can change those signatures manually but I won't recommend