# Dynamic Link Library & Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, dynamic-linking

I made a dll in C++ and wrote this class in java:

```
public class VolumeControl {

    public native float GetVolume();

    public native void SetVolume(float val);

    public native void VolumeUp();

    public native void VolumeDown();

    public native void Mute();

    static {
         System.load("some_path/VolumeControl.dll");
    }
}
```

it works good, if I call functions from this file, but when I'm trying  to do this:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VolumeControl ctrl = new VolumeControl();
        ctrl.Mute();
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
RemoteControl.VolumeControl.Mute()V
```

Both classes are in the same package, of course. How can I solve it? Thanks.

**Update1**: OK the problem was, that I added these classes to package. When I move them to default package, everything works good. But now if I want to use this dll with different packages, I need to rebuild it.

**Update2**: Actually I can't add it to package at all, when I'm trying: #javah VolumeControl, I get Error:

```
Could not find class file for 'VolumeControl'.
```

**Update3**: I added manually name of package to C++ functions and it works. Thanks.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358541/jni-hello-world-unsatisfied-link-error thread on UnsatisfiedLinkError.  I think it will help.

Comment: Hi. The problem is when I'm trying to call Mute() from Server class, but if I put this main into VolumeControl class, it works good.

Answer (score 0):

The use of javah utility may help if integrated into a makefile to ensure the interface is always assumed on both side (client/server).