# Java Native link in code error

Tags: java

I'm trying to load a native library from code like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(System.getenv("ProgramFiles"));
builder.append("\\MyLib\\custom_library.dll");
System.load(builder.toString().replace("\\", "/"));
```

The `.load` method seems to be working. But when I try to access anything from the specified `custom_library.dll`, it fails saying:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no custom_library in java.library.path

Why is my library not loading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNI Hello World Unsatisfied Link Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358541/jni-hello-world-unsatisfied-link-error)

Comment: Did you search previous questions? I think this is asked almost every day.

Comment: I did, for sure. But I tried their solutions with no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occur when the file does not exist in `java.library.path`:

> When a Java application loads a native library using the System.loadLibrary() method, the java.library.path is scanned for the specified library. If the JVM is not able to detect the requested library, it throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

You need to check first if the `C:\Program Files\MyLib` directory exists within the `java.library.path`:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

If not exists, you need to configure it, see [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html).

If you still get the error, it seems that something is wrong with the library and cannot be loaded.