# Java not loading dependent libraries

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNI for the first time but when I run my java program I keep on getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. The error says that it can't find my dependent libraries. I did see the question [JNI Hello World Unsatisfied Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358541/jni-hello-world-unsatisfied-link-error) but their recommendations did not work. As a side-note I don't own microsoft visual studio and I'm running on windows 10.

I am using the following commands in order to compile and run my program:

`javac HelloWorld.java`

`javah HelloWorld`

`gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include/win32" -shared -o HelloWorld.dll HelloWorld.c`

`java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld`

**Source Code:**

Java Source (`HelloWorld.java`):

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }
    private static native void sayHello();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHello();
    }
}
```

Generated header file (`HelloWorld.h`):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C file (`HelloWorld.c`):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    printf("C says hello!");
}
```

Comment: The solution is to make sure the dependent libraries are available via the PATH.

Comment: By path, do you mean the environment variables or in the command itself?

Comment: Did you make sure that JRE and library have the same architecture (32/64 bit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here for a simple HelloWorld sample:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo001

(Linux/OSX).

In case you want to use shared library, make sure JVM can see it. You can use: "-Djava.library.path=" or you should make sure library is on LD_LIBRARY_PATH.